# Rails config/routes.rb file is not working (see body)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

When I start rails server via command line: `rails server`, or via RubyMine (just hitting run button) server starts just like it's expected.
Console output: 
 
`/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/projectName/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development` 
`=> Booting WEBrick` 
 
`=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000` 
 
`=> Call with -d to detach` 
 
`=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server` 
 
`[2013-07-07 19:59:37] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1` 
 
`[2013-07-07 19:59:37] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [i686-linux]` 
 
`[2013-07-07 19:59:37] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7480 port=3000`

The problem arises when I'm trying to get to the web-site. For some reason it is not rendering any of the pages, I'm constantly getting `Not Found: 'anyControllerNameHere'` and there are not any logs of trying accessing the web-page in development.log file, although when I run rake db:migrate it's getting logged. Tried to access with `127.0.0.1:3000/`, `localhost:3000/`, `0.0.0.0:3000/` and running server on another port, no luck.

When i run `wget localhost:3000/` in the console, I'm getting: 
`--2013-07-07 20:00:06--  http://localhost:3000/` 
`Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1` 
`Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.` 
`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found` 
`2013-07-07 20:00:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.`

My machine: `Ubuntu 13.04`, `Rails 3.2.11`, `Mysql 5.5`

I'm new to Linux and Rails, so maybe I missed something simple and important. 
Please suggest any ideas.
Thanks

Comment: Could your `root` route in `config/routes.rb` be pointing to some controller that does not exist?

Comment: It's strange, because when I write in the command line `bundle exec rake routes` I get the correct list of routes. I guess server for some reason is not refering to the `routes.rb` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The thing is that I start working with already written application and it appears that root for the application itself was rewritten in `config/unicorn.rb` file with `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/appName"`.